# How can I convert OpenSSH public key into OpenSSL in Ruby (or Rails)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have public keys in a database and need them to validate JWT tokens.  The keys are in OpenSSH public key format, so I need to convert them into PEM format like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAx9jNrkPwjH12qVhmpKs/MLfvsYy5uob+jx68Mdsv5tmZG5HVq6nm
sYKkcDdwLseShWREIOmB0lC/bhaaihuAvs4ZZcDRKnrq2FX+WQz9/mHScr1kQTgB
adRdQWzG3KXeOJJiKSBfNHVn3Iixdba/IX5rYhARbDMqPQfwz08gKHbFLuNogNN0
hm5yTFQU1z0bhR87dHFJgfwQSVloeNKTsXleoGZqGBNbjMdF0HOEvQaWzenQHJde
dTaF39Ok6q0k4QsSHyuzmoXy30O3oe31D7mu4QQOk/Lj61zVZrR25YvGYpn0ym+d
cWxKFyeVX/McstRhu7wD1iu0kj74A2VhrwIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Is there a way to convert a OpenSSH public key into a OpenSSL one with Ruby (not with openssl)?

I already found this:
https://gist.github.com/tombh/f66de84fd3a63e670ad9
But unfortunately it's throwing an error in recent Ruby versions.  See last comment which I got as well:

```
undefined method `e=' for #<OpenSSL::PKey::RSA:0x00007ff593ba87c8>
```

I get this in Ruby 2.4.9

I also found the SSHKey gem but that doesn't seem to offer that functionality.

Comment: We'd like to know where you researched this, why that didn't help, the minimal code that demonstrates the problem with what you tried. See "[ask]" and all the linked pages. Currently it looks like you want us to write code or recommend resources for you, both of which are off-topic.

Comment: "_unfortunately it's throwing an error in recent Ruby versions_" -- you must include in your question what steps you've taken to resolve this yourself and any errors you encountered, along with example code and Ruby versions directly in your post. Don't make us hunt down the code and guess at how you ran it so we can then guess again as to whether or not the errors we encountered are the same you encountered. If you've done work to resolve this on your own then tell us what it is and what didn't work.

Comment: The error is in the last comment in the gist.  The gist  has the code to reproduce.  I've now repeated the error in my question.

Answer (score 1):

By using the gem:

```
gem 'net-ssh'
```

You can do the following:

```
converted_key = Net::SSH::KeyFactory.load_public_key('~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')
```

or if from memory:

```
converted_key = Net::SSH::KeyFactory.load_data_public_key(public_key)
```